# SumProduct for two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 years worth of hourly **price** data in columns as so..

```
DateTime, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
```

I have another data set of **volumes** for 24 hours in similar format..

```
DateTime, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
```

I have put these two into dataframes. I would like to find the most efficient way of finding the sumproduct of Price and Volume for **Each day**.
The result would be

```
Date, Sumproduct
XX-XX-XXXX, $$$$$$
```

I am lost other than doing a iterative loop by filtering each day and hour and summing it. Thank you

Comment: One **Clarification** the first set of data (PRICE) is for HISTORY (2010-01-01 to Yesterday) of 5 years and HOURLY.. the second set of data (VOLUME) is for one day (today). I want to run a simulation that gives me the sum product of the VOLUME*PRICE for each day in history basically ignoring the datetime in the VOLUME df.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a dataframe that is the dot product of your price df and volume df, and then groupby on `date` (which can be obtained by `.date` on a `pd.DatetimeIndex`) and aggregate by `sum`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some artificial data
# ===============================================
np.random.seed(0)
df_price = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, 100, (48,4)), index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=48, freq='H'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
print(df_price)

                     Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
2015-01-01 00:00:00    94    97    50    53
2015-01-01 01:00:00    53    89    59    69
2015-01-01 02:00:00    71    86    73    56
2015-01-01 03:00:00    74    74    62    51
2015-01-01 04:00:00    88    89    73    96
...                   ...   ...   ...   ...
2015-01-02 19:00:00    94    64    82    54
2015-01-02 20:00:00    53    95    61    72
2015-01-02 21:00:00    63    95    61    66
2015-01-02 22:00:00    74    79    71    96
2015-01-02 23:00:00    75    66    69    83


df_vol = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 20, (48,4)), index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=48, freq='H'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
print(df_vol)

                     Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
2015-01-01 00:00:00    13     5     9    16
2015-01-01 01:00:00    16    14    11    10
2015-01-01 02:00:00    18    12    13    13
2015-01-01 03:00:00    14     7    13    11
2015-01-01 04:00:00    16    11    18    14
...                   ...   ...   ...   ...
2015-01-02 19:00:00     9     8     8    13
2015-01-02 20:00:00    13    16    18    16
2015-01-02 21:00:00    19    12     5     8
2015-01-02 22:00:00    13    12    12    18
2015-01-02 23:00:00    15     6    13     9


# processing
# ==========================================
df_product = df_price * df_vol
df_product.groupby(lambda idx: idx.date).agg(sum).sum(axis=1)

2015-01-01    85298
2015-01-02    85761
dtype: int64
```

### Edit:

As mentioned by @holroy, if your price data is in hourly frequency while volume data in daily frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some artificial data
# ===============================================
np.random.seed(0)
df_price = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, 100, (48,4)), index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=48, freq='H'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
print(df_price)

                     Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
2015-01-01 00:00:00    94    97    50    53
2015-01-01 01:00:00    53    89    59    69
2015-01-01 02:00:00    71    86    73    56
2015-01-01 03:00:00    74    74    62    51
2015-01-01 04:00:00    88    89    73    96
...                   ...   ...   ...   ...
2015-01-02 19:00:00    94    64    82    54
2015-01-02 20:00:00    53    95    61    72
2015-01-02 21:00:00    63    95    61    66
2015-01-02 22:00:00    74    79    71    96
2015-01-02 23:00:00    75    66    69    83


df_vol = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 20, (2,4)), index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=2, freq='D'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
print(df_vol)

            Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
2015-01-01    13     5     9    16
2015-01-02    16    14    11    10

# processing
# ========================================
df_price.groupby(lambda idx: idx.date).agg(sum)

            Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
2015-01-01  1744  1832  1659  1684
2015-01-02  1729  1750  1722  1928

# the sum product
# ==========================
(df_price.groupby(lambda idx: idx.date).agg(sum) * df_vol).sum(axis=1)

2015-01-01    73707
2015-01-02    90386
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does this take into account that one of the OPs data frames is on an hourly base, whilst the other is using days? Isn't that a part of the problem to convert the hour based data frame into a day based data frame?

Comment: @holroy Sorry that I misunderstood your question. For your case, just apply the same `groupby.agg(sum)` logic to hourly price dataframe, and then calculate dot product with daily volume data. Finally sum over `axis=1`. See the edit.

Comment: Not mine question, but it looks better now I think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to calculate the mean price for the day, and then apply it to the volume:

```
prices.resample('D', how='mean').multiply(volume)
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments below (where I assume your price and volume timestamps match), I believe the following will work:

```
prices.multiply(volume).sum(axis=1).resample('D', how='sum')
```

This multiples price times volume for each matching column, sums up the total for all columns in that row (i.e. hour), and then uses resample to sum up the results for each day.

Comment: I cant do that .. i truly need a sumproduct because i want to have get the weighted price and not a simple average price..

Comment: What are your weights? Your volume is daily, and your price samples are in hours. Is there additional information?

Comment: My volume is for one day.. and NOT daily but has 24 hours of data.. so each hour and each column has different data.. so if i want to write it out it would be... sumforDay1(Price_Day1_Col1_Hour1*Vol_Col1_Hour1,Price_Day1_Col2_Hour1*Vol_Col2_Hour1..... etc)